# Error defining empty node in tree data structure in scala

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

The following code is running into `not found` error in intellij

```
case class Node[A](value: A, left: TreeNode[A], right: TreeNode[A]) extends TreeNode[A]
case class Leaf[A](value: A, left: Empty, right: Empty) extends TreeNode[A]
case object Empty extends TreeNode[Nothing]
```

Here is the error when I try to compiler the code

```
Error:(10, 36) not found: type Empty 
case class Leaf[A](value: A, left: Empty, right: Empty) extends TreeNode[A]
                               ^
```

I am not exactly sure why `Empty` could not be found, since I defined it in `case object`.

Any hint would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With objects you have to use their singleton type:

```
case class Leaf[A](value: A, left: Empty.type, right: Empty.type) extends TreeNode[A]
```